# Why does Hamas choose violence over peaceful means?

Tags: israel, palestine, armed-conflict, hamas

What does Hamas realistically think it can achieve by continuing to use violence against Israel? It seems to me that if the Palestinians engaged in peaceful deliberations they would have achieved their own state long ago and that by continuing their terrorist activity they have undermined the cause.

Comment: Not to defend Hamas, but `I can’t help but notice of the Palestinians engaged in peaceful deliberations they would have achieved their own state long back.` needs some sources.

Comment: Quite a few comments deleted. Please reserve comments for requests for clarification or constructive criticism. If you'd like to provide an answer, please write a real answer that conforms to our quality standards.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The question does not ask about what Hamas's goals are, but rather why they reject arbitration (or other non-violent strategies) as a means of achieving them. That is what this answer will primarily address.

### Original rejection of arbitration

To understand their reasoning, we should go back to Hamas's original Covenant (quotes from the [translation](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/20th_century/hamas.asp), original [here](https://www.aljazeera.net/2005/07/16/%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%82-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B3)) to understand why they rejected peaceful deliberations and other non-violent or less-violent methods (or at least their public reasoning). **Hamas talks *extensively* about their reasoning.** First, they frame the conflict as a religious struggle. **As such, they argue that peaceful methods are contary to their principles.** Although Hamas uses religious reasoning extensively throughout its Covenant, it bears mentioning that this is based on *Hamas's* interpretation of Islam, which is decidedly conservative and militaristic, but that **this interpretation is not characteristic of Islam as a whole.**

> Initiatives, and so-called peaceful solutions and international
> conferences, are in contradiction to the principles of the Islamic
> Resistance Movement. Abusing any part of Palestine is abuse directed
> against part of religion. Nationalism of the Islamic Resistance
> Movement is part of its religion. Its members have been fed on that.
> For the sake of hoisting the banner of Allah over their homeland they
> fight. "Allah will be prominent, but most people do not know."
>
> <sub>*Hamas Covenant*, Article 13</sub>

Further, **Hamas argued that the parties that would arbitrate deliberations would not be sufficiently competent or interested in doing justice.** They also seemingly imply that it, given that they consider Israel and Palestine to be rightfully Muslim territory,<sup>1</sup>  non-Muslims should not judge matters in the land:

> Now and then the call goes out for the convening of an international
> conference to look for ways of solving the (Palestinian) question.
> Some accept, others reject the idea, for this or other reason, with
> one stipulation or more for consent to convening the conference and
> participating in it. Knowing the parties constituting the conference,
> their past and present attitudes towards Moslem problems, the Islamic
> Resistance Movement does not consider these conferences capable of
> realising the demands, restoring the rights or doing justice to the
> oppressed. These conferences are only ways of setting the infidels in
> the land of the Moslems as arbitraters. When did the infidels do
> justice to the believers?
>
> <sub>*Hamas Covenant*, Article 13</sub>

They argued that direct fighting represented the only means of success. Other methods, to their minds, were doomed to failure.

> There is no solution for the Palestinian question except through
> Jihad. Initiatives, proposals and international conferences are all a
> waste of time and vain endeavors. The Palestinian people know better
> than to consent to having their future, rights and fate toyed with.
>
> <sub>*Hamas Covenant*, Article 13</sub>

**In short, Hamas would simply disagree with the notion that they are undermining their cause through their use of violence. In fact, if they still adhere to the beliefs in their charter, they believe that the use of arbitration would undermine their cause.**

### Potential practical difficulties

Although Hamas does not necessarily mention this explicitly in the Covenant, I think we can reason a bit further. **Some of their goals would be difficult to achieve through non-violent means, and they are undoubtedly aware of that.**

The Covenant more or less implies that Hamas views the entirety of Israel as occupied territory in need of liberation, not just East Jerusalem, the Gaza Strip, and the West Bank (i.e. Palestine). This goal, clearly, would be quite difficult to settle amicably as long as a significant non-Palestinian population lives in the region. *However*, subsequent statements have been more open to a peace process, and the group has said at various times that it would potentially accept an agreement in which Israel withdrew to the 1967 borders.

Further, Hamas wants an end to the Israeli occupation of Palestine, but they want more than that. They want a religious Muslim government.

> Under the wing of Islam, it is possible for the followers of the three religions - Islam, Christianity and Judaism - to coexist in peace and quiet with each other. Peace and quiet would not be possible except under the wing of Islam. Past and present history are the best witness to that.
> It is the duty of the followers of other religions to stop disputing
> the sovereignty of Islam in this region.
>
> <sub>*Hamas Covenant*, Article 31</sub>

In fact, their primary disagreement with the Palestinian Liberation Organization
was that the latter was too secular:

> Because of the situations surrounding the formation of the
> Organization, of the ideological confusion prevailing in the Arab
> world as a result of the ideological invasion under whose influence
> the Arab world has fallen since the defeat of the Crusaders and which
> was, and still is, intensified through orientalists, missionaries and
> imperialists, the Organization adopted the idea of the secular state.
> And that it how we view it.
>
> Secularism completely contradicts religious ideology. Attitudes,
> conduct and decisions stem from ideologies.
>
> That is why, with all our appreciation for The Palestinian Liberation
> Organization - and what it can develop into - and without belittling
> its role in the Arab-Israeli conflict, we are unable to exchange the
> present or future Islamic Palestine with the secular idea. The Islamic
> nature of Palestine is part of our religion and whoever takes his
> religion lightly is a loser.
>
> <sub>*Hamas Covenant*, Article 27</sub>

Given that in the region as a whole (Israel plus Palestine), there are more Jews than Muslims, as well as a significant and likely growing number of [non-religious Palestinians](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-48703377) and a handful of Christians, Hamas is likely aware that this sort of government would be difficult to achieve through non-violent means.

That said, it is worth noting that they generally state that Islamic law should be established [through democratic means](https://web.archive.org/web/20151118123632/http://www.bloomberg.com/apps/news?pid=newsarchive&sid=aB2RfynNbLmk):

> Hamas officials say they have no plans to impose Islamic law. “What
> you are seeing are incidents, not policy,” said Younis al-Astal, a
> Hamas legislator. “We want Islamic law to be the standard, but we
> believe in persuasion.”

However, while this may work for Palestine, I suspect that Hamas must be aware of the challenges it would present in Israel.

A further factor, which likely does not apply to all members of Hamas, is anti-Semitism. Although the original charter contains many statements that could be seen as anti-Semitic, in recent years Hamas has stated, at least publicly, that they do not have any dispute with Jews for the sake of being Jews. However, several high-ranking members have made statements suggesting that they would like to see violence visited upon Jews (or sometimes, just Israelis) for its own sake, not simply as a means to ending the occupation. For [instance](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/04/01/world/middleeast/01hamas.html):

> For example, in a column in the weekly Al Risalah, Sheik Yunus
> al-Astal, a Hamas legislator and imam, discussed a Koranic verse
> suggesting that “suffering by fire is the Jews’ destiny in this world
> and the next.”
>
> “The reason for the punishment of burning is that it is fitting
> retribution for what they have done,” Mr. Astal wrote on March 13.
> “But the urgent question is, is it possible that they will have the
> punishment of burning in this world, before the great punishment” of
> hell? Many religious leaders believe so, he said, adding, “Therefore
> we are sure that the holocaust is still to come upon the Jews.”

While such statements undoubtedly do not represent the public policy of Hamas and may not even represent the majority opinion, it seems likely that there are a significant number of members who do dislike Jews or Israelis and would like to harm them for non-utilitarian reasons. Even when not framed in those terms, it is likely that many more members would like retribution against the *Israeli government*.

<sub>1: By right of conquest. Article 11: "This is the law governing the land of Palestine in the Islamic Sharia (law) and the same goes for any land the Moslems have conquered by force, because during the times of (Islamic) conquests, the Moslems consecrated these lands to Moslem generations till the Day of Judgement."</sub>

Comment: At some point, I will update the answer to include the perspective of the 2017 charter, as well as my suspicion that the principles of the 1988 charter are very much still in play.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124557/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-bjorn-lindqvist).

Comment: "contary to their principles" I think that should be "contrary".

Comment: And re "Given that in the region as a whole (Israel plus Palestine), there are more Jews than Muslims...", it's perhaps useful to note that many (41% per Wikipedia) Israeli Jews are actually secular, and presumably would strenuously object to being subjected to ANY religous government. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secularism_in_Israel#Differences_in_the_Jewish_population

Answer (score 23):

From Hamas’ perspective, Israelis drove Palestinians out of the Palestinians’ ancestral land through war and terrorism, and continue to oppress, abuse, expropriate, and kill Palestinians to this day. They reject the Jewish religious argument that God gave that land to the Jews, and see no justification for the state of Israel; they only see the imposition of an oppressive Jewish state backed by Western (ex-colonial) powers.

The main goal of Hamas (as with most terrorist groups) is to:

1. Bring their complaint into the public realm in a way that is difficult to ignore or silence, and…
2. Force Israel to be increasingly violent and oppressive, making Hamas look increasingly righteous

It’s tremendously sad that Hamas rejects the passive ‘civil disobedience’ model outlined by Thoreau and used so effectively by Gandhi and Martin Luther King. I can’t fault their complaint, but their methods leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: I am downvoting, because the "Jewish religious argument" is not the only argument out there, not even amoung right-wing parties in Israel. The fact that Israel was the historic homeland of the Jews is an at least equally common argument adduced these days, which plays particularly well with ethnonationalists like Netanyahu's base. While that's a pretty bad reason for ethnic cleansing an oppression, mentioning that Israel/Palestine is Palestianians ancestral land but neglecting to point out the the same is true of Israeli's feels...irresponsible.

Comment: Besides, your answer implicitly seems to endorse all aspects of Hamas's complaint outlined in your answer, e.g. "no justification for the state of Israel." There are no justifications for Israel's past and present atrocities, but that is a rather different matter than believing Israel should not exist, which is what Hamas believes. A bit like how many Americans (possibly even including you?) believe that there is no justification for the USA's indubitably genocidal foundation, or its history of racism and oppression, but don't say that that disqualifies the US from existing.

Comment: @Obie2.0: I don’t endorse anything; the question asks for Hamas’ perspective, and I tried to give it. With respect to ancestral homelands… If ancient Jewish history were not enshrined in Christian  religious dogma, Jews would have the same status as the ancient Assyrians or Macedonians: I.e., as a group that once dominated a swath of territory, long ago, and lost it. If Jews can walk in after 2000 years and say “hey, this land is ours”, why can’t native Americans kick everyone out of (say) Buffalo NY?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124554/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-wrigley-why-does-hamas-choose-violence-over-peaceful).

Comment: Hamas is a mass political movement, whose parliamentary candidate list is in the majority and forms the government of the Palestinian authority (constitutionally, albeit not the one recognized by Israel and the US). Calling them a "terrorist group" is effectively trolling. Regardless - it is not true that Hamas has, as a goal, the forcing of Israel to be increasingly violent and oppressive. That claim seeks to absolve Israel of responsibility for its own acts ("But Hamas made us do it").

Comment: @einpoklum: The [Irgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irgun) was a Jewish paramilitary force internationally recognized as a terrorist group; several of its members (e.g. Menachem Begin) became prominent political figures in Israeli politics, and the group itself morphed into the Likud party, which largely dominates in Israel. Being a political leader and being a bloody-minded bastard are not by *any* means mutually exclusive. And your last statements are merely naïve or misinformed. Modern politics in far too many cases reduces to a game of ethical 'chicken', with everyone playing victim.

Comment: @TedWrigley: If you're drawing parallels between Hamas and the Herut movement (with the Irgun as its military wing), then you would be claiming that Israel is run by a terrorist group... as for the game of chicken - it is not symmetric. People don't play the game of Chicken when on the first round they get assassinated and their friends and family lose their houses or are also killed.

Comment: "I don’t endorse anything"... well you kinda do, in the last sentence "I can’t fault their complaint".

Comment: @Fizz: Being against human misery isn't an endorsement of anything. No one should experience misery, no one should have misery inflicted on them by others, and I'm not narrow-minded enough to assert that *this* side or *that* side is at fault. Everybody's at f***ing fault. Everyone who points fingers is looking in a mirror, whether they know it or not; everyone who throws stones lives in a glass house. And yes, that includes you, and me. You might want to reflect on that…

Answer (score 6):

> what does Hamas realistically think it can achieve?

"Realistically" is a tricky qualifier. Also, questions about people's thoughts, private and collective, are problematic. That being said - here's my perspective on what Hamas *may* think it can achieve:

1. Continuing and increasing casualties and costs for Israel for its direct occupation of Palestinian land (and I'm being vague here regarding whether it's 1967-occupied land or 1948-occupied land) and its siege of the Gaza strip.
2. Israeli withdrawals from Palestinian land, in favor of an independent Palestinian state/proto-state.
3. Easing of the Israeli siege on Gaza.
4. Maintenance and strengthening of the commitment of Palestinians (again, vagueness regarding which part of them) to the struggle for Palestinian national liberation.
5. Increased awareness to the Palestinian plight, in the Arab world, the Islamic world and the world in general.
6. Adoption by Palestinians of Hamas' intra-societal views, e.g. the role of Islam in society and various related cultural preferences.
7. Better social welfare than whatever Fatah would institute.

Naturally you could argue about how much of this is realistic, and how much of this is desirable (and about what constitutes an independent state). But assuming you agreed on desirability, Hamas can make a decent argument about the achievability, and in fact about past gains, on most of the above.

> I can’t help but notice that if the Palestinians engaged in peaceful deliberations they would have achieved their own state long back.

With respect - I would claim that statement is either naive and misinformed, or facetious. I strongly suggest you read up on the history of the Zionist movement in Palestine.

> If Hamas were ever to pose a real threat, they would lose this cover and Israel will purge the Gaza Strip.

Hamas' military wing is not an army which could face the Israeli one and prevail. It's true that Hamas, and other factions and phenomena among the Palestinians do pose various threats to US, Saudi and Israel interests (not necessarily in that order); however, since Hamas is not a "terrorist group" but a large and deeply-rooted political movement - the kind of "purge" you are suggesting is a out-and-out genocide of the people of the Gaza Strip and the West Bank (where many support Hamas as well). Israeli politicians and military leaders occasionally bring up such a purge in their rhetoric, hinting that by hitting some choice targets and driving around on tanks through Gaza they might make Hamas go away.

At any rate, there are restraining forces - internal and external - which have curtailed Israeli destruction and killing so far to a level at which the genocidal effects are insufficient to root out Hamas.

> By continuing their terrorist activity they have undermined the cause.

You seem to be assuming that "the cause" is "An entity called a state which Israel agrees to".

For me, it is quite difficult to decide whether Hamas' tactics have been more of a help or more of a hindrance. They have certainly had both benefits and detriments.

> And unfortunately a lot of pro-Palestinians have failed in condemning them, further hurting the cause.

See above. Also, ["Let he who is without sin cast the first stone"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let_him_who_is_without_sin_cast_the_first_stone).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124609/discussion-on-answer-by-einpoklum-why-does-hamas-choose-violence-over-peaceful-m).

Answer (score 6):

Hamas is a national liberation movement whose stated goal is to free
Palestine from Israeli occupation. The occupation of Palestine was
imposed by violence and Hamas believes that violence is necessary to
end the occupation. Though it should be emphasized that Hamas has not
chosen violence *over* peaceful means - it has chosen *to complement*
peaceful means with violence.

Hamas is not the only national or popular group fighting perceived
injustice that has chosen violence. Other groups include

- the Russian Bolsheviks who fought the Russian Tsar,
- the Yugoslav partisans who fought the Nazi occupation,
- various Zionist groups who fought the British in Mandatory Palestine,
- the African National Council who fought the apartheid regime in South Africa,
- and the Irish Republican Army who fought the British in Northern Ireland.

These groups choose violence for the same reason: because it works. If
you like science fiction, you might enjoy this clip: [Star Trek - TNG:
Data on the Effectiveness of
Terrorism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiqnN6EU3Q0) Who is right:
Data or Picard?

Hamas didn't start out as a violent organization. In 1973, the
wheel-char bound preacher Sheikh Ahmed Yassin found Hamas predecessor,
the charity the Islamic Center (al-Mujama al-Islamiya), in Gaza, as an
ofshot to the Egyptian Muslim Brotherhood (MB). The MB is, by and
large, a non-violent organization, although it has been involved in
some coup attempts in Arab countries. Yassin's religious charity was
not concerned with worldly affairs. As such, it was in opposition to
the secular left-wing Fatah movement led by Yassir Arafat. Infamously,
Israel even supported the Center as it saw the Center as a useful
counterweight to Fatah.<sup>1,2</sup>

In 1987, the First intifada broke out. The Center decided that they
needed to involve themselves. According to rumors, against Yassin's
wishes, the Center's leadership decided on militancy and Hamas - an
acronym for the Islamic Resistance Movement (Harakat al-Muqawamah
al-Islamiyyah) - was founded. During the first few years of the
intifada, Hamas's mostly limited its use of violence to
Palestinians. For example, it punished and sometimes executed
Palestinians spying for Israel. Hamas also tried to prohibit
prostitution, curb the flourishing drug trade in Gaza, and the selling
of alcohol and pornography.<sup>3</sup> It also captured Israeli
soldiers and demanded the release of Yassin and other Hamas members
held by Israel in exchange. Israel refused these exchanges and the
soldiers were either killed by Hamas or died during botched Israeli
rescue attempts.<sup>4,5</sup>

Eventually, it became riskier for Palestinians to collaborate with the
Israeli government and the drug epidemic abated. Thus, from Hamas
perspective, its violence was successful.

Hamas's violence intensified following a massacre committed by a
Jewish settler in Hebron in 1994. He killed 29 Palestinians praying in
the Ibrahimi mosque.<sup>6</sup> Hamas began carrying out suicide
bombings against Israeli civilians, reasoning that if the Israeli side
targeted civilians so could it. According to some authors, Hamas's
violence derailed the ongoing peace process between the Palestinian
Liberation Organization (PLO) and Israel, which they
opposed.<sup>7</sup> According to others, the peace process was a sham
and doomed from very beginning.<sup>8</sup> Assuming the first view is
correct, Hamas again achieved its goal using violence.

Fast-forward to 2006. Hamas and other militant groups in Gaza raid
Israel and capture the soldier Gilad Shalit. Some years later Israel
is forced to exchange Shalit for over 1 000 Palestinian prisoners. Yet
another example of achieving a goal using violence.

Hamas may also have looked at its rival Fatah which practically has
ceased using political violence. Fatah has not been able to extract
any notable concessions at all from Israel. To the contrary, the
Israeli government is now contemplating formally annexing parts of the
West Bank. Given Fatah's strategy's failure, Hamas may have concluded
that the liberation of Palestine requires violence.

- 1. [How Israel Helped to Spawn Hamas](https://web.archive.org/web/20090926212507/http://online.wsj.com/article/SB123275572295011847.html)
- 2. [Hamas: Origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamas#Origins)
- 3. [Memories of Revolt: The 1936–1939 Rebellion and the Palestinian National Past](https://books.google.com/books?id=lvdIDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA196) (p. 196)
- 4. [Negotiating Under Fire: Preserving Peace Talks in the Face of Terror Attacks](https://books.google.com/books?id=F5EmiYXQUcsC&pg=PA86) (p.86)
- 5. [Hamas: The Islamic Resistance Movement](https://books.google.com/books?id=ozLNNbwqlAEC&pg=PT75) (p. 75)
- 6. [Cave of the Patriarchs massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_of_the_Patriarchs_massacre)
- 7. [Sabotaging the Peace: The Politics of Extremist Violence](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3078606)
- 8. [Belated Occupation, Advanced Militarization: Edward Said’s Critique of the Oslo Process Revisited](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/430979?seq=1)

Comment: Actual experts on Muslim Brotherhood (that being, the government of Egypt, not western apologists) would strongly disagree with your opinion of how peaceful they are.

Comment: Can you cite some of them?

Answer (score 1):

- *if the Palestinians engaged in peaceful deliberations they would have achieved their own state long ago*

this is a common misperception or, I would say, propaganda in the West. Interestingly, they stick this propaganda only to non-western countries/people, not for themselves.

If all disputes could be solved in peaceful means then there would have been no WW1 and WW2. Right? And, what about the Irish struggle for independence from the UK? What about the American Civil war? What about Falklands War?

Can Germany or Poland take back the land they lost to the USSR from the Russian Federation in a peaceful means?

Can Ukraine take Crimea back from Russia through dialog?

Comment: There is one basic difference between all the other examples given and the Palestinian issue; It's true that the Palestinians can't achieve all their aspirations via diplomatic dialogue. But on the other hand, international recognition for the parts of the land that they do fully control (i.e. Gaza and Area A & B) is being withheld due to their terrorist activities. So it makes sense to say that they seemingly lose more than they gain from this 100 year old campaign of terrorism.

Comment: @Jacob3, Would Ukraine be satisfied if Russia offers to return 3/4 of Crimea? Is Ireland satisfied with not having Northern Ireland back? The essence of the problem is, Israel is seeing "9" and Hams is seeing "6".

Comment: The Palestinians will never get everything they want, no matter the tactics. The question is; If they wouldn't have declined the UN partition plan, wouldn't we have had now a Palestinian State since 1948? If Jordan, Egypt & Syria would have not engaged the whole Arab world in an attempt to annihilate the little Jewish State in 1967, would have Israel gotten control of Judea & Samaria? If right now, the PA and Hamas will put a final end to the 100 year old campaign of terrorism, will the international community not recognize their sovereignty over the land that they do control?

Comment: @Jacob3, *The Palestinians will never get everything they want, no matter the tactics* --- Ireland is not getting Northern Ireland back, no matter the tactics. Ukraine is not getting Crimea back, no matter the tactics. Spain not getting Gibraltar back, no matter the tactics. Argentina is not getting Falklands back, no matter the tactics.

Comment: @Jacob3, *The question is; If they wouldn't have declined the UN partition plan, wouldn't we have had now a Palestinian State since 1948?* --- The question is, why didn't Ireland, Ukraine, Spain, Argentina agreed on partitioning the disputed lands withe the respective occupying forces? At least they could have retrieved part of the land they lost!

Comment: @Jacob3, *If right now, the PA and Hamas will put a final end to the 100-year-old campaign of terrorism, will the international community not recognize their sovereignty over the land that they do control?* --- the terminologies you are using like "terrorism", "international community", etc. are vague terms. Coz, these terms mean opposite things to different communities, and they are not agreed upon by all of the disputing parties. these are relative terms.

Comment: @Jacob3, Also, if the USA stops vetoing resolutions against Israel on a regular basis, Israel would be history in one week. If any other superpower replaces the USA, Israel **may not** exist on the face of the earth. Most of the countries who are abstaining from voting in case of the resolutions against Israel might choose to vote against Israel if they would not have to be scared of the USA.

Comment: #1 There is no point in dividing Crimea, Ireland or Gibraltar, as their population is almost homogeneous and they should decide on their own who should rule their place - Unlike Israel/Palestine which wasn't a sovereign state - since the Roman conquest, was largely depopulated and always maintained a significant Jewish population (the Turkish census of Jerusalem in 1864 shows a majority of Jews). #2 The intentional killing of babies is considered Terrorism according to all interpretations. #3 The US hasn't been such a devoted friend of Israel in the early years.

Answer (score -7):

Hamas cannot make any choice, they can just react to the circumstances. The power to choose peaceful means or violence is just in the hands of Israel which has military and political over most of the country, all of the borders and all cross borders and internal movements.

Comment: This is nonsense.  Israel has no interest in attacking Hamas &c purely for the sport of it.  Hamas persists in attacking Israel, which merely tries to defend itself.

Comment: Israel agreed to leave Gaza in 2005, as per the desire of the international community, to try and see how an independent Palestinian State would be like. Then a terrorist organization by the name of Hamas took over the place (and killed all the Fatah officials), thus forcing Israel "and Egypt" to shut the border. Who doesn't know what followed?... Have the Gazans agreed to build a normal state, they would have now been like Bahrain.

Comment: @Jacob3 Isn't it strange that in a parcel of land completely surrounded where everything that gets in and out is strictly controlled Hamas can get enough weapons to control the local population, but not enough weapons to defend from the Israeli attacks? Isn't the status quo very useful for Israel?

Comment: @FluidCode, Israel would wish to have a similar relationship with Gaza as it has with the UAE. To smuggle AK-47s thru tunnels under the closed Egyptian border is quite simple, but to build an anti-aircraft missile system against Israel's F-35s is something that even Russia hasn't really mastered.

Comment: @Jacob3 The tunnels you mention go to a country which is controlled by a military junta which is in very good relationship with the Israeli government. If AK-47s are allowed to reach the tunnels there must be Isreali approval.

Comment: @jamesqf *Israel has no interest in attacking Hamas &c purely for the sport of it. Hamas persists in attacking Israel, which merely tries to defend itself.* --- how do u explain Jewish settlements in Palestinian lands and Jewish robbery of Palestinian properties? Should Hamas respond to that or not?

Comment: @user366312: How are those lands "Palestinian"?   Land is owned by people (and business &c), not by ethnic groups.  As to "robbery", if you're talking about 1948 &c, the people involved chose to abandon those properties.  I'd also refer you to the concept of eminent domain, which is common among governments that derive from the British legal tradition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminent_domain

Comment: @jamesqf, so, what is your solution to the Palestinian problem? Why not grab all their land and just declare them refugee/stateless? Why are u grabbing so slowly? What fear do u have?

Comment: @FluidCode, Obtaining riffles for illegal activities is an easy task for terror and crime groups in almost every country, especially in less developed regions. Just add the fact that ISIS has a very active branch in the Sinai.

Comment: @user366312: Unfortunately, it is a problem without a plausible solution.  What they NEED to do is a) admit that they lost the wars; b) admit that they (and the rest of the Arab world) were wrong to start them in the first place; and c) give up the ideology of hatred.  In other words, they need to emulate Japan after WWII.

Comment: @jamesqf, *admit that they lost the wars* --- actually, they haven't lost the war yet, they are continuing. *b) admit that they (and the rest of the Arab world) were wrong to start them in the first place* --- they were not wrong. they just couldn't find the backing of France and the USA. *c) give up the ideology of hatred* --- that is more true of Zionists rather than Palestinians.

Comment: @user366312: Well, they've lost all the wars to date :-)  And having backing has nothing to do with right or wrong.  If Germany had won WWII, and backed the Arabs in a successful genocide, it still would have been wrong.

Comment: @jamesqf, We can talk about those 53 vetos the USA gave in UNSC in favor of Israel during the past 5 decades. War is not lost yet. Resistance is something that is going on. It will continue until the end of time. You hope that the USA stays as a superpower forever.

Comment: @user366312: Don't see how security council votes are relevant, but did you ever stop to think that perhaps the US supports Israel because Israel is in the right?  And that Hamas &c are persistent violators of basic human rights, not just in their tactics against Israel, but in their behaviour towards their own people?

Comment: @jamesqf *Don't see how security council votes are relevant* --- Yes, I also see why you don't see that. *perhaps the US supports Israel because Israel is in the right?* --- So, since when the USA has been carrying the flag of truth and justice on this distressed planet? If they really are, then Saudis are also right in Khashoggi's murder and the bombing of Yemen as the USA supports them? *And that Hamas &c are persistent violators of basic human rights* --- perhaps you should think why 53 resolutions were raised in the UNSC against Israel.

Comment: @user366312: So what's to respond to?  Ever stop to think that those Security Council votes might be motivated by things like anti-Semitism, anti-Americanism, or just plain oil money?  Or that sometimes your choices are not between good and bad, but between bad and worse?

Comment: @jamesqf, *anti-Semitism, anti-Americanism* --- why is there nothing similar in the case of other countries, say, China (Uyghur), Turkey(Kurds), etc? why do UN members-only target Israel? *or just plain oil money* --- this is just a plain conspiracy theory. Everyone knows how close those petro-dollar countries to Israel are.